# Save Workbook using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

my goal is to open an existing Excel file and create a new named range. The creation of the named range seems to work but I have to save the file afterwards (I guess). When saving using `wb.write(fileOut);` it generates a 0KB file.

Do I need to iterate over the whole data and send it to the OutputStream ? Or is there another possibility (maybe using FileInputStream ?)

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*
import java.io.*

xlFileAddress = '/tomcat-etl/webapps/etlserver/data/files/ProductSales.xlsx';

Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(xlFileAddress));

Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

// create named range
Name namedCell = wb.createName();
namedCell.setNameName("newName1");
reference = "Sheet1!\$A\$1"; // area reference
namedCell.setRefersToFormula(reference);

try {
    OutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(xlFileAddress)
    wb.write(fileOut);
}

catch(Exception e) {
    LOG.info("Exception:")
}
```

Comment: You can't do a save-in-place with the existing file open

Comment: Using `Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(xlFileAddress));` the file stays open. So it cannot be overwritten. Do `Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(xlFileAddress));` instead. And do closing `fileout` and `wb` after `wb.write(fileOut);`. So `wb.write(fileOut); fileOut.close(); wb.close();`.